# How to establish mutual secure connection with openssl?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I try to establish mutual (2 way) secure connection with server. I should use client certificate (CRT filetype) in no SSL3 mode.

*command:*

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -no_ssl3 -cert client.crt
```

*output:*

```
140386483435168:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

When I don't use required cert, it has different output.

*command:*

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -no_ssl3
```

*output:*

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 DC = com, DC = example, O = blah, OU = blah, CN = blah
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
140181058492064:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1262:SSL alert number 40
140181058492064:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=blaaaah/L=blaaaah/O=blaaaah/OU=blaaaah/CN=example.com
   i:/DC=com/DC=example/O=blah/OU=blah/CN=blah
 1 s:/DC=com/DC=example/O=blah/OU=blah/CN=blah
   i:/DC=com/DC=example/O=blah/OU=blah/CN=blah
 2 s:/DC=com/DC=example/O=blah/OU=blah/CN=blah
   i:/DC=com/DC=example/O=blah/OU=blah/CN=blah
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
blaaaah
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=blaaaah/L=blaaaah/O=blaaaah/OU=blaaaah/CN=example.com
issuer=/DC=com/DC=blaaaah/O=blaaaah/OU=blah/CN=blaaaah
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/DC=com/DC=example/O=blaaaah/OU=blaaaah/CN=blaaaah

.
.
.
.etc.

---
SSL handshake has read 5458 bytes and written 330 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DES-CBC3-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DES-CBC3-SHA
    Session-ID: B1259877305945E0AAAAAA2FE38DA46B5A5813F6513D0DC5BF92FB6AD32287569
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: blaaaah
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1450452192
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
---
```

What is the wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, you need private key for your certificate (and possibly a password, if it's encrypted - you'll get a prompt). Therefore you need to add `-key myPrivateKey.key`, assuming it's PEM encoded.